# how to get value from div and place it within img tag src in php

Tags: jquery, html

value is coming from this table on clicking a row :

```
<script>
    var link_base = "<?php echo bloginfo('template_url').'/savelabel/'; ?>" ;
    var img_name = $('#imgdiv').text();
    $('#imgid').attr('src', link_base + img_name);
</script>
<div class="bx2">
    <img id="imgid" alt="" class="imgsty" />    
</div>
```

Selected filename is showing in a div :

```
<div id="txtdiv"></div>
```

And within html, there is an image tag, in which I want to pass value of `div` (ie the name of image file) into `src=""` within img tag.

The code which I am trying to achieve this is as shown below :

```
<script>
  var link_base = "<?php echo bloginfo('template_url').'/savelabel/'; ?>" ;
    var img_name = $('#imgdiv').text();
    $('#imgid').attr('src', link_base + img_name);
</script>
<div class="bx2">
    <img id="imgid" alt="" class="imgsty" />    
</div>
```

Comment: The id of the filename div is `txtdiv`, use `var img_name = $('#txtdiv').text();`

Comment: i have checked that, the result is the same problem

Answer (score 6):

wrap your script in `$(document).ready(function(){...your code ...});`, this will ensure that your DOM structure is ready to process like image in your case is ready to change its src

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var link_base = "<?php echo bloginfo('template_url').'/savelabel/'; ?>" ;
    var img_name = $('#imgdiv').text();
    $('#imgid').attr('src', link_base + img_name);
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move script under `img` - when you try to set `src` attribute, no image exists.

```
<div id="txtdiv"></div>

<div class="bx2">
    <img id="imgid" alt="" class="imgsty" />    
</div>
<!-- here or in header link jQuery -->
<script>
    var link_base = "<?php echo bloginfo('template_url').'/savelabel/'; ?>" ;
    var img_name = $('#txtdiv').text();
    $('#imgid').attr('src', link_base + img_name);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying but it is still not working. Moreover in Javascript Console it is showing :  Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost/website/wp-content/themes/website/savelabel/". Please help

Comment: @Suneet: it works: http://jsfiddle.net/L08hthpq/. There was just typo (taken from you), `imgdiv` vs. `txtdiv`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this fiddle. The code runs at onload https://jsfiddle.net/2z7ux3et/2/

It's just an example, you can use any image you want:

```
<div id="imgdiv">Information_icon.svg</div>
<div class="bx2">
    <img id="imgid" alt="" class="imgsty" />    
</div>
$(function() {
    var link_base = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/' ;
    var img_name = $('#imgdiv').html();
    $('#imgid').attr('src', link_base + img_name);
});
```

Comment: shall i send my code to you. May be there is something wrong there.

Comment: what results do you have in link_base and img_name?

Comment: link_image is showing the full path but img_name is blank. And I think that is why in Javascript Console this is showing :  Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost/website/wp-content/themes/website/savelabel/". In div id="txtdiv", name of the image file is displaying, on clicking row in the table

Comment: try to put the script at the end of the page

Comment: No, it's still not working. is there any provision to send a screenshot of the output to you

Comment: I have added a screenshot. Pls see this

Comment: Please help me in solving the problem. You can see above in the edit , image file name is displaying but is not transferring in the variable using the code :   var img_name = $('#txtdiv').html();  Why??

Comment: first verify if you have multiple ids with same name for txtdiv and if so you should put distinct id for each row and seccond what comes to my mind is to try to put an .click event on the row and after the row is populated with the image name to make the .text() request...

Comment: When I put my code in the jiddle, it work fine. Then why it is not working within the code. Where I am wrong. Please check my code. You can see this "http://jsfiddle.net/suneetp/eybhq19u/6/"

Comment: I found the problem. The script should not be below bx2, instead it should be below the script from where the name of image file is coming

Comment: That's I was trying to say... to put the script at the end to see if any other script needs to run first. Glad you've done it.